# Can't display image in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Following is the piece of code in shiny.server. It works perfectly fine and loads the image in local computer. But whenever I try to host the app in shinyapps.io server the image doesn't show up. Please guide what's the problem and how to solve the same?

```
output$tb<-renderUI({
  if(is.null(data()))
    h5("developped by Kinsuk ",tags$img(src='shinysnap.jpg',height=350,width=600))
  else
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About File",tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data",tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary",tableOutput("summ")),tabPanel("Centered Variables",dataTableOutput("MeanC")))

})
```

Comment: Did you upload the image to the server? Where exactly did you place it in relation to the file containing this code?

Comment: Hi.. No That's what am missing.. How to upload the image in server ? Couldnt find any option there .. Could you please share a thought ?

Comment: When you upload your app on shinyapps.io, your image should already be in your app folder.

Comment: yeah .. It's there only under "www" folder. But still not coming somehow. any way out to solve this ?

Comment: when you say "works perfectly local", you do mean after having restarted both R and the environment? Do you see the tag "developped by K" but not the image? please be more specific.

Comment: yeapp.. exactly that's the case..everything shows online in the server except that Picture

Comment: Well, hard to tell! I tried to create an app with your piece of code but it works fine. Can you publish a reproducible minimal application code? or give us the link to the deployed app?

Comment: https://kinsukghatak.shinyapps.io/shiny_centering_final/

Comment: Hi @agenis , this is the link to my app. as u can see, none of the images are coming into display while the app is working from server. Pls suggest if there is any way out to this.. I kept the image in the "www" folder of my shinyapp in my hardrive.. The app is performing perfectly in the server except the images

Comment: Thanks. When i load the app homepage there is an image that displays perfectly well (a printscreen of an excel with 2 textboxes in it). Is it this one that you don't see?

Comment: @KinsukGhatak any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your image file from ".jpg" to ".png". It may work.
I had similar issue, and I got it resolved by converting jpg image to png format.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to double check the spelling of your image name.

I had an image called (let's say) iMage.jpg, and the path image.jpg. Locally it found the correct image (in the www folder), but on shinyapps.io it didn't presumably because it is case sensitive there.